# How does cs go rank system work

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I played the first 10 competitive and got ranked to silver 1.

And, when I won my 20 competitive match my rank didn't change, why is that?

I don't understand how the rank system in the game works.

Comment: Valve hasn't discussed their internals much, but it's safe to assume that your matchmaking rating is very similar to Dota2's. That's described here: http://blog.dota2.com/2013/12/matchmaking/

Comment: Indeed,they are similar since they are both based on the Elo rating system...which most competitive games today use.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system

Comment: So the rank doesn't have to go up every 10matches it depends on my win or loss and how I preformed in rounds

Comment: @user69234 Yes. And the more you play, the more it will count your wins/losses and the less it will count your K:D score.